# 16 bits program in x64 machine

Tags: memory, assembly, cpu

I would like to understand why programs do not work on 16bit computers with x64 operating system installed on it..

What happens on the question 'Assembly' of the computer?

I mean, talking in assembly language, that does not work, as the processor understands this?

Comment: If you're talking about running 16-bit DOS applications on newer versions of Windows; the 16-bit compatibility mode was removed from Windows after XP (IIRC). If you want to run such applications on newer versions of Windows, use an emulator/VM like DOSBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this is no longer possible is, because in the 64 bit long mode, the CPU doesn't support v86 and real mode, only protected mode code. In order to support this, MS would have to implement an emulator in Windows and there are already several good ones available. So they decided to drop support for this after XP.